# How can I replace the spaces in a string with two different characters?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a column of data strings that look like so `1402 2010 10`

I want to replace the first space with an underscore and the second with a forward slash so that it would look like this `1402_2010/10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gsubfn` you can write a function which keeps track of the index of the match `count`, e.g. 1 for first match , 2 for second match, etc., and change the replacement accordingly

```
gsubfn(' ', proto(fun = function(this, x) c('_', '/')[count]), v)
#[1] "1402_2010/10"
```

Or, same idea with base R using Reduce

```
seq_sub <- function(x, pattern, replacement){
  Reduce(function(x, y) sub(pattern, y, x), replacement, init = x)
}

seq_sub('some words here ', ' ', c(9, 5, 2))
# [1] "some9words5here2"
```

Answer (score 3):

An idea via `sub`,

```
sub('(^[0-9]+)\\s([0-9]+)\\s([0-9]+)', '\\1_\\2/\\3', '1402 2010 10')
#[1] "1402_2010/10"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can nest `sub` as follows:

```
x <- c("1402 2010 10")

sub(" ", "/", sub(" ", "_", x))

#"1402_2010/10"
```

`?sub`

> sub(pattern, replacement, x).

- `x` is a character vector where matches are sought.

The trick here is to use a `sub` in place of `x` (which matches the first space it finds with `_`) and the outer `sub` replaces the first space it finds with `/` which happens to be the second space for x.

**Note**: This replaces only the first and second space in case your string has more number of spaces.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the other one posted earlier? - Though yours is much more complete...

Comment: That uses a `gsub` which replaces the whole string as indicated in my note. For example if `x <- c("1402 2010 10 200")`. I think otherwise, I can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, nesting `sub()` (for the first space) and `gsub()` (for the others):

```
   v <- "1402 2010 10"
   gsub(" ","/",sub(" ","_",v))
   [1] "1402_2010/10"
```